# Git client integrated with Finder

Tags: macos, git, svn, version-control, github

Is there a git client for Mac OS that integrates with Finder to put badges like ticks and crosses on files representing their version status, like tortoiseSVN and Dropbox do?

Comment: gitIcons is free and small. https://apps.apple.com/app/giticons/id1546740440?mt=12

Answer (score 10):

Following @viskin, I recently find another small app named [SnailGit](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snailgit-free-git-client-finder/id1099475282?mt=12), that pretend to be Tortoise-like for Git and Finder

Comment: Great finding. Looks like that one comes from same developer as Git Status. But SnailGit has much more features.

Comment: Does snailGit support Rebase? Also, is there a trail version to check the software (https://langui.net/snailgit/)

Answer (score 5):

I use a Finder replacement software called [Pathfinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/). Pathfinder has builtin Git and Subversion support. Pathfinder is not open source, or even freeware, but if you're a developer on a Mac, it is worth the price. If you are using Github, [Github for the Mac](http://mac.github.com) is a good choice.

That said, I still do most of my Subversion and Git work directly from the command line. You have better control, and the ability to integrate Git commands with various Unix command line tools. Unless you're using an IDE like Eclipse, there's no better way to work with Git than the command line.

Besides, I'm old school and believe GUI development environments are for sissies. You want to develop on the Mac? [Here's the software for you](http://www.secretgeometry.com/apps/cathode/). Put it in full screen mode, and you'll know what VT100 terminal emulation is all about. Maybe you'll even pick up a little Fortran.

Comment: are you worried about the security implications of the closed-source software?  should one be?

Answer (score 2):

GitFinder (https://gitfinder.com/) is also another option which is integrated with Finder for MAC OS

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this tiny app called [Git Status](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/git-status-free/id1041863924?mt=12).

There is free version and full version that costs $2.

You should manually add your project folder to the app. After doing so Finder will display handy overlays over files just as you want.